# PHP search multidimensional array with more than one result?

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I found a way to search my multidimensional array and output the result and it works, however it only finds the first match and stops.  If I have more than one match in the array I want to be able to show them all.

My array looks like this (the first layer of keys goes from 0, 1, 2 etc):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mydevice] => blahblah
            [ipadd] => 10.10.10.209
            [portnum] => 16040
        )
```

---

```
function searcharray($value, $key, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
       if ($val[$key] == $value) {
           return $k;
       }
   }
   return null;
}

$myoutput = searcharray($ptn2, mydevice, $newresult);
```

I can then echo the results using something like `$newresult[$myoutput][mydevice]`.

However if I have more than one entry in the array with a matching data in the 'mydevice' key it doesn't return them (just the first one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `return` breaks the function. You could use something like this:

```
function searcharray($value, $key, $array) {
    $result = array();    
    foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
        if ($val[$key] == $value) {
            $result[] = $k;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Now you will always get an array as result - empty if nothing was found. You can work with this like this e.g.

```
$mydevicekeys = searcharray($ptn2, "mydevice", $newresult);
foreach ($mydevicekeys as $mydevicekey) {
    // work with $newresult[ $mydevicekey ]["mydevice"]
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  It returns one or more results (if it finds more than one).

Answer (score 0):

So add the results to an array :)

```
function searcharray($value, $key, $array) {
   $res = array();
   foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
       if ($val[$key] == $value) {
            $res[] = $key;
       }
   }
   return $res;
}
```